# Python - How to append integer in list and to sort?

Tags: python, list

i want append in list and to sort

For example

```
num_list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
num_list.append(13)
num_list.append(17)

print(num_list)
[5, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20]
```

Comment: Use `num_list.sort()` for sort.

Comment: I think you can use any search engine to find how to do ...

Comment: did you search this before posting your question here ???

Comment: sorry, I missed the word 'same time'. i want append and sort in same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list is already sorted, you can insert directly at the correct place: This does the insertion and keeps the list sorted in `O(n)`.
(credits to @AntonvBR for the assist in the comments)

```
def insert_sorted(seq, elt):
    """inserts elt at the correct place in seq, to keep it in sorted order
    :param seq: A sorted list
    :param elt: An element comparable to the content of seq
    Effect: mutates the param seq.
    Does not return a result
    """
    idx = 0
    if not seq or elt > seq[-1]:
        seq.append(elt)
    else:
        while elt > seq[idx] and idx < len(seq):
            idx += 1
        seq.insert(idx, elt)

num_list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
insert_sorted(num_list, 21)
num_list
```

Edit:

You could also use the module bisect, and do the same, probably more efficiently: (credits to @stefan in the comments)

```
import bisect
num_list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
bisect.insort(num_list, 17)
```

Comment: [`bisect.insort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, however even bisect finds the index in log(n) time, the insertion is O(n).

Comment: Good catch, thank you @AntonvBR - I fixed it.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Nice but it returns a duplicate now. Need to use a return after append or else statement

Comment: Good catch again! Thank you. I added your assist in the credits.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the [`bisect.insort()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) function:

```
import bisect

num_list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
bisect.insort(num_list, 13)
bisect.insort(num_list, 17)

print(num_list)
# [5, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20]
```

Worst/Average case `O(n)` time complexity for insertion and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use default `sort` method

```
    num_list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
    num_list.append(13)
    num_list.append(17)

    num_list.sort()
    print(num_list)
```

Comment: there's no need to answer low quality duplicate questions

Comment: There are thousands, not just a few elemental, because i want append and sort at the same time

Comment: @ChanghoLee Are we supposed to guess what you want to do ? :)